# Convert Array to Magento2 Collection

Tags: magento2, collection, pagination, array

I am converting an Array to Magento2 Collection

```
        $items = $this->getItems();
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
        $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $varienObject->setData($item);
        $collection->addItem($varienObject);
        }
        return $collection
```

Now When I apply pagination on this collection

```
        $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
```

Not working it is showing all the records on one page although setavailable limit is showing correct values.

[image]

Here is my code for applying pagination

```
    if ($this->Test()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'productpartsfinder.bysize.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5 => 5, 10 => 10, 15 => 15, 20 => 20));
        $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
        $pager->setCollection($this->Test());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->Test()->load();
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to Convert an array to a collection in magento2:

```
$dataArray = [];
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $objectManager- >create('Magento\Framework\Data\Collection');

foreach ($dataArray as $key => $row) {
   $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
   $varienObject->setData($row);
   $collection->addItem($varienObject);
}
return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

For limiting a collection use `setPageSize()` and `setCurPage()` methods:

```
$collection 
    ->setPageSize(5) // only get 5products 
    ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
    ->load();
```

Comment: I have already added this in my code but still it is not working